# eclipse plugin to create hibernate annotated entities?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

i know that hibernate tools can create hibernate entities but the hibernate mapping will be in XML file, but i was wondering if there's a tool to create hibernate entities and the mapping will be with annotations not in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your java code and use Source > Generate Hibernate/Jpa annotations and hibernate tools will do an attempt to add necessary annotations based on that

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to Generate JPA annotations using hibernate tools. I am looking for simillar kind of process.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate tools can also generate the annotated entities by reverse engineering of your database. You have to choose `Generate EJB3 annotations` and `Domain code(.java)` . Refer to the [4.5. Reverse Engineering and Code Generation](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/#refeng_codegen) more info.
[image]

Comment: hmmmmmmmm, i was thinking of something like a wizard to enter the fields and the relations and annotations.